# `require ('file.php')` stops my code and display blank page

Tags: php

I'm trying to call a PHP class in my project called `connectBDD_PDO.class.php` located in `/wamp/www/publicClass/connectBDD_PDO.class.php`, but when I use the function

```
require ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/publicClass/connectBDD_PDO.class.php');
```

My code stops and displays a blank page, no error messages even in debugging mode. Can you help me find where the problem come from ?

Comment: Wamp stores error logs in wamp/logs/php. Can you check if your error is present in that error log?

Comment: Most likely there are errors in that file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` usually is the domain name, depending on how your vhost configured.

A invalid path is causing the error.

Just give the absolute path of the directory where **publicClass/connectBDD_PDO.class.php** is located. You may use a relative path, but then it must be seen relatively from the script is including it.

When seeing a blank page, probably a HTTP 500 error is invoked. You may place `ini_set('display_errors', true);` at first line to debug in browser, but does not guarantee to show it.

Example assuming

```
/var/www/www.foo.com/htdocs/index.php
/var/www/publicClass/connectBDD_PDO.class.php
```

Then you can include this like

```
// absolute path
require('/var/www/publicClass/connectBDD_PDO.class.php');
```

or

```
// relative path
require('../../publicClass/connectBDD_PDO.class.php');
```

Comment: Since the OP is using `require` it probably won't HTTP 500 though, it'll just stop and trigger a PHP error.

Comment: Depends on configuration of the webserver, I would say.

Comment: Thanks, putting the absolute path did the trick ! I'll try out the `ini_set() `next time :)

Comment: You might be right - but either way it's the combination of `require` and `display_errors` being off, with an invalid filepath that's causing the problem - so your answer should sort it anyway ;) @MarkusZeller

Comment: I've refined the answer a bit. Hopefully all people are now satisfied.